# Create an Html with OpenTBS

Tags: php, pdf, docx, dompdf, opentbs

I'm using `tbs '3.8.0'` with `OpenTBS Plugin version 1.7.6` to create a docx.
In the same project I have `dompdf.cls.php 468`

I know that I can't convert directly a docx to a pdf, so I'm trying to use `OpenTBS` to create a valid input for `Dompdf`.

Is there a way to create an html with OpenTBS, or something that I can pass as a valid input to Dompdf ?

As now my docx is created in this way:

```
    $TBS = new \clsTinyButStrong;
    $TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
    $TBS->LoadTemplate('path'.$fileName, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
    $TBS->Show(OPENTBS_STRING, $fileName.docx");
```

Comment: My limited understanding from reading the marketing blurb is that OpenTBS is just a tool for substituting values _inside_ Office files. I'm not sure it actually understands the files to the level needed to convert to a different format such as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyButStrong is a Template Engine that works with any text template. So it fits well to merge HTML pages, and it has some facilities for that. TBS can also merge XML files for example.

Meanwhile, OpenTBS is a plug-in for TinyButStrong that makes it merge Ms Office and LibreOffice documents. Ms Office and LibreOffice documents are technically Zip archives containing XML subfiles. Without OpenTBS, the TinyButStrong template engine cannot merge such documents.

So if you ant to merge HTML pages in order to convert them into PDF using Dompdf, then TinyButStrong (without the OpenTBS plug-in) can do that without problem.

See examples https://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php